# how can I build a lucene query with two or more "in" clauses

Tags: lucene

My document in Lucene (solr, really) has several fields, lets call them textField1, numField1, numField2.

My application will have a list of search terms words1 textField needs to query against, a list of numbers list1 for numField1, and another list of numbers list2 for numField2.

I will like to create a Lucene query that does this:

```
textField matches one or more words in words1
AND either (
    numfield1 is one of the values in list1 OR
    numfield2 is one of the values in list2)
```

I'm trying to use BooleanQuery to build the query, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. It seems the AND and OR boolean operations map to the different enums in BooleanClause.Occurs, but I can't glean from the documentation how they map to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to get [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) and play with it until you are sure your query is correct and brings back what you want.

When you're done, you can have a look at [parsed query](http://code.google.com/p/luke/source/browse/wiki/img/search.png?r=16&spec=svn70) (hint: click on *Explain structure*) and it will show you how BooleanQueries are stacked.

Just make sure you are using the same analyzer you used to index the documents.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

> textfieldl1:words1 AND (list1:numfield1 OR list1:numfield2)